# How to handle multiple angles in relation to velocity?

Tags: c#, math, xna, velocity, angle

I'm having an issue where I have say, an object in the middle, then I want to shoot a projectile out from the object. I did a lot of trig/geometry to get the proper angles & lengths of the sides for this "invisible triangle" so to speak, but I'm having an issue with the velocities of the projectiles.

I'd like to standardize the speed so that it's the same for all projectiles. Unfortunately I find that trying to get the exact angle coupled with standardizing the velocity, results in me only able to shoot in the 8 directionals (Up, Down, Left, Right, Up-Right, Down-Right, Down-Left, Up-Left).

For example, if my projectile speed is 3, then I have 8 options:

( 0,-3) = Up

( 3,-3) = Up-Right

( 3, 0) = Right

( 3, 3) = Down-Right

( 0, 3) = Down

(-3, 3) = Down-Left

(-3, 0) = Left

(-3,-3) = Up-Left

Is there a good way to handle this situation or do I just need to flex my math skills more to find and account for the "in between" angles with better math?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you are already doing the trig then you already have your answer for calculating your X/Y speeds. X = Cos(angle) * 3 and Y=Sin(angle)*3.

Answer (score 0):

To get the speed of the projectile given velocity in x and y coordinates, just use the good ol' Pythagorean theorem.

```
(Projectile Velocity)^2 = (X-Velocity)^2 + (Y-Velocity)^2
```

For your examples:

```
Up, Right, Down, Left directions =>  Projectile Velocity = 3

The other directions => Projectile Velocity = Sqrt(9 + 9) = 4.24264069
```

If you want to find the X-Velocity and Y-Velocity such that your projectile speed is exactly 3 in all cases, you need to use trigonometry [as Kratz described in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246886/how-to-handle-multiple-angles-in-relation-to-velocity#comment48594983_30246886).